# c# URL POST Web API

Tags: c#, api, http-post

I'm trying to do a function which work with WECHAT API, 
Here is my code:

I use the code below to get a connection Token

```
internal static string Token(string CorpID, string Secret)
    {
        CorpID = CorpID ?? "wwe1f80304633";
        Secret = Secret ?? "Ev7_oVN7RqD9k4yUy5pzkfcZ_QhX9l0VjZnAQ";

        string token;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            token = wc.DownloadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={CorpID}&corpsecret={Secret}");
        }
        if (token.Contains("access_token"))
        {
            return token.Split(',')[2].Split(':')[1].Replace("\"", "");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

It's successful to get a valid token from WECHAT Server,

And the code below is I want to POST a request to WECHAT API and ask WECHAT to Send Message to selected Department Person.

```
internal static string SendMsg(string sendtext)
    {

        string ACTOKEN = "" + PDC.MSGTOKEN + "";
        string CONTENT = "" + PDC.CONTENT + "";
        string PostUrl;
        using (var wc2 = new WebClient())
        {
            PostUrl = wc2.UploadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/send?access_token={0}{1}", ACTOKEN, CONTENT);
        }


        return "";
    }

public static void SendMsg2()
    {

        PDC.CONTENT = "Test Message";
        string MsgContent = "{\"toparty\": \"" + PDC.DEPTID + "\",\"msgtype\": \"text\",\"agentid\": \"" + PDC.AGENTID + "\",\"text\": {\"content\": \"" + PDC.CONTENT + "\"},\"safe\":0}";
        SendMsg(MsgContent);

        MessageBox.Show("" + MsgContent + "");
    }
```

And I Added a button on my WinForm and trying to make it work

```
private void BtnSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string token = MSG.Token(null, null);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            PDC.MSGTOKEN = token;
            MessageBox.Show("" + PDC.MSGTOKEN + "");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Invalid Token ");
        }

        MSG.SendMsg2();
    }
```

However seems it doesn't work, and if I'm not wrong the problem on this part

```
internal static string SendMsg(string sendtext)
    {

        string ACTOKEN = "" + PDC.MSGTOKEN + "";
        string CONTENT = "" + PDC.CONTENT + "";
        string PostUrl;
        using (var wc2 = new WebClient())
        {
            PostUrl = wc2.UploadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/send?access_token={0}{1}", ACTOKEN, CONTENT);
        }


        return "";
    }
```

May anyone can give me some ideas how I can solve this problem ? Many Many Many Thanks ~

Comment: I'm really hoping the ID and secret you provided aren't real values, if so do you want to maybe get rid of them for your own safety?

Comment: Yes, it's not real id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has been done my Code without Problem, this is the code below for everyone who need.

The code to get Token from Https API

```
internal static string Token(string CorpID, string Secret)
    {
        CorpID = CorpID ?? "" + PDC.CorpID + "";
        Secret = Secret ?? "" + PDC.Secret + "";

        string token;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            token = wc.DownloadString($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={CorpID}&corpsecret={Secret}");
        }
        if (token.Contains("access_token"))
        {
            return token.Split(',')[2].Split(':')[1].Replace("\"", "");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The Method of POST

```
internal static string PostWebRequest(string PostUrl, string ParamData, Encoding DataEncode)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = DataEncode.GetBytes(ParamData);
            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(PostUrl));
            webReq.Method = "POST";
            webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            webReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream newStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default);
            ret = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            response.Close();
            newStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

The code to using WECHAT WORK for sending Message

```
internal static string SendMsg(string CorpID, string Secret, string ParamData, Encoding DataEncode)
    {
        string AccessToken = Token(CorpID, Secret);
        string PostUrl = string.Format("https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/send?access_token={0}", AccessToken);

        return PostWebRequest(PostUrl, ParamData, DataEncode);
    }

public static void SendMsg2()
    {
        string sCorpID = "" + PDC.CorpID + "";
        string sSecret = "" + PDC.Secret + "";
        PDC.CONTENT = "Test Message";

        string Message = "Test";


        string MsgContent = "{";
        MsgContent += "\"totag\": \"" + PDC.DEPTID + "\",";
        MsgContent += "\"msgtype\": \"text\",";
        MsgContent += "\"agentid\": \"" + PDC.AGENTID + "\",";
        MsgContent += "\"text\": {";
        MsgContent += "  \"content\": \"" + Message + "\"";
        MsgContent += "},";
        MsgContent += "\"safe\":\"0\"";
        MsgContent += "}";

        SendMsg(sCorpID, sSecret, MsgContent, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

The Button Event for active Send Message Function

```
private void BtnSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string token = MSG.Token(null, null);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            PDC.MSGTOKEN = token;
        }

        MSG.SendMsg2();
    }
```

Comment: how do you get  'PDC'. Any DLL can provide

Comment: ($"https://qyapi.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/gettoken?corpid={CorpID}&corpsecret={Secret}"); -- should be @ ?

Comment: @user3538475 The PDC is only a Module that I use it to store some information inside. So my PDC.DEPTID is call the PDC module and find DEPTID inside